# django css file not recognised - wrong configuration?

Tags: css, django, url, templates, settings

in my app, i want to use a css file, but the tempalte doesn't 'know' where the file is, though i've configured it as in tutorials:

in the urls.py (the urls file in the root of the site, not belonging to an app)

```
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT}),
```

in the template

```
<link href="/site_media/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the settings:

```
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = '/site_media'
```

where can i be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [django-annoying](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home), it's a very useful app with plenty of convenient decorators, middlewares and functions. If you add `StaticServe` middleware like that, Django will serve static if `DEBUG = True` without explicitly setting in urls.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'annoying.middlewares.StaticServe',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',              
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',               
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',                    
)
```

Second, check your `MEDIA_URL` (in your case it's `STATIC_DOC_ROOT`, but you should use `MEDIA_URL`) and `MEDIA_ROOT` path. `MEDIA_ROOT` should point to absolute path to your static directory. This is how I do it in setttings.py:

```
import os


def rel(*x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

# MEDIA_ROOT will point to media directory where settings.py is located
MEDIA_ROOT = rel('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

You can use the same function to set path to your `templates` dir.

Comment: i've used this method, thanks a lot! it was not necessary to install the annoying middleware, for now it wors fine without:D
Thanks again!

Comment: surely it isn't necessary, but I really like django-annoying app and thought you may find it useful:)

Answer (score 2):

The `document_root` argument to `static.serve` needs to be the location of the file *on the server filesystem*, not the URL. So unless your css file really is in the `/site_media`  directory on your disk, which seems unlikely, you want something else as `STATIC_DOC_ROOT`.

Comment: though i've read it 3 times, i really don't understand what you mean.
should i change the STATIC_DOC_ROOT path to the absolute one on my disk or?...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: it works now, but i've used an url, importing and using the 'os' in the settings.py. it is too much headache with the absolute path, and it seems hardcoded:D
Thanks so much for support!:)